# Сайт Asp.Net Core не доступен из глобальной сети по статическому ip

Tags: iis, asp, iis-10

Сайт доступен в локальной сети по ip - 192.168.1.15:6100
Из глобальной сети он не доступен. У меня статический ip.
Пробовал установить apache 2.4 с портом 85, все работало, даже из глобальной сети.
Брандмауэр отключен.
Порты в модеме прокинуты.
Удостоверение ApplicationPoolIdentity
Привязки правильные

Comment: Вы уверены, что он "статичный"? Такая услуга обычно **покупается** у провайдера за доп. плату в месяц, где вам провайдер выделяет уникальный IP, через который уже и идет доступ. Если у вас так, то проверяйте настройки, проверяйте привязанные IP в IIS.

Comment: установил IIS сервер на другую машину, все работает
пришел к выводу что windows server 2012 r2 блокирует нужные мне порты, брандмауэр отключен полностью, ну и на всякий пожарный добавил правила для порта. 
может групповая политика блокирует порты.
Ip статический точно, так как проброс порта для radmin на основной сервер нормально работает.